# Font y tamaño de letra en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**Buenas, tengo una pregunta, ¿Cómo puedo ver el tamaño de la fuente en el diseño del formulario? Actualmente, uso esto para aumentar el tamaño:

```
        using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 15.0f))
        {
            label1.Font = font;
            label2.Font = font;
        }
```

Pero, esto solo funciona en tiempo de ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el diseño no:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguno sabe como puedo hacer que se vea en diseño?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La fuente del formulario y de cualquier elemento dentro de el, la puedes cambiar en la ventana de propiedades como te muestro en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Genioo, muchísimas gracias